Calculating probabilities of revisiting a state and average number of possible words
In a class on Markov Chains, we were tasked with solving the following exercise. I have managed to solve (1) and I believe (2) as well, since there are only a small finite number of paths, for which I can calculate the probabilities.
Now I am having a hard time understanding how to approach (3), since from what I can tell, there are a lot of possible paths that can satisfy the given condition. Could someone point me in the right direction here? I am thinking that maybe I could express the probability as the sum of the transition probabilities that would create a valid path in some concise way. Would that be correct?
As for (4), It is my understanding that I should be able to use the static state of the system by calculating the π vector, select the appropriate column and then multiply by the appropriate transition probability. However, that produces 1/6 for all π values, if I am not mistaken, which then yields 0 if I use the transition probability of ΑΒΓ->ΓΑΒ. Any tips on my approach? Am I completely off?
The exercise:

In an anagram game, each round is given a three-letter word formed
using the letters A, B, and Γ, and a new word is produced by choosing
two positions {i, j}, i, j = 1, 2, 3, i < j, and swapping the letters
in these positions. For example, if the current word is ΑΒΓ and the
positions {1, 2} are selected, the next word is ΒΑΓ. The probabilities
of selecting positions {1, 2} and {1, 3} are 1/4 and 1/8 respectively.

Model the game via a Markov chain, assuming that all words are initially equally likely.
Calculate the probability, starting from the word ΑΒΓ, that the word ΓΑΒ will eventually be produced without having produce the word
ΓΒΑ.
Calculate the probability, starting from the word ΑΒΓ, that the same word will eventually be produced again without before producing
the word ΓΑΒ.
Calculate the average number of words produced to produce the word ΓΑΒ starting from word ΑΒΓ.



For $4$, I suggest working with states.  You have $6$ states, corresponding to the $6$ permutations.  Let $E_S$ be the expected numbert starting from state $S$, write down the transitions, and solve the linear system.  It's $6\times 6$ of course, so it's not exactly easy to do by hand.

@lulu Thank you, do you mean the π vector that is produced by the 6x6 equation system? If so, I have already calculated that and found all values to be 1/6. Should I leave it at that and not multiply by any transition probability?

You don't have a $\frac 16$ chance of reaching all states from a given state.  Indeed, you can only reach three others.  For instance $ABC$ can reach $BAC, ACB, CBA$ only, each with probability $\frac 13$.  Thus, for instance, $E_{ABC}=1+\frac {E_{BAC}+E_{ACB}+E_{CBA}}3$ is one of the $6$ equations I mentioned.

To stress, you don't need to work with the full transition matrix, though it can be useful.  You can just solve those $6$ equations.

CORRECTION:  hold on.  I didn't notice that the probabilities weren't uniform.  That makes my equation wrong.  Should be: $E_{ABC}=1+\frac {E_{BAC}}4+\frac {E_{CBA}}8+\frac 58 \times  E_{ACB}$.

@lulu Are E_subscript in this case mean values (using probabilities)? Sorry I haven't seen it being used with markov chains in our class so far.

As I said, $E_S$ denotes the expected number of trials it will take to reach $CAB$ given that you are currently in state $S$.  Thus, $E_{CAB}=0$ and $E_{ABC}$ is the answer you are looking for.
